# How can I Adapt an already built antlr4 Cobol parser into antlr3 interfaces

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlr3, xtext

I have built an antlr v4 grammar for parsing Cobol files. It is tested and fully functional. Now I need to adapt it to be used within a XText project (with unfortunately uses antlrv3). How can I achieve it without backporting my grammar (and loosing all already built Listeners and Visitors)?

After a few thinking about the problem I am wondering if there is a way to generate antlr v3 interface adaptors to use antlr v4 Parser and Lexer. If so, i could "tweak" XText, so it would be using my already built antlrv4 classes through this adaptor interface.

Anyone already had done something like this?

Comment: i would very much like to see at the grammar... Anyway, AFAIK COBOL is not LL(n) for any given n, and that precludes the possibility to use antlr3, you will need to run antlr4, because backporting the grammar to v3 is simply not possibile. Your only chance is to tweak XText to use the real antlr4

Comment: Thank you for your observation. Backporting is not one of my options.... The idea was tweaking XText indeed. About the grammar itself, as i mentioned before, i cannot share it. But i can tell you guys that it is not a full featured grammar. I had to relax **a lot** of COBOL syntax rule validations to have it working. But it worked for my project, so it´s ok.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently working on this problem as well. Is there a possibility to look at your grammar file?

Comment: Unfortunately I can´t share the grammar itself, but we could be exchanging thoughts through here. I look at the problem from a conceptual and implementation viewpoint. Since we have antlr4 java classes for the grammar, one could implement (or extend) some classes of antlr3 to "call back" the antlr4 classes. That´s the general idea...